# Hiding a tab from tab bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code for tabs in a HTML file

```
<div class="tabbable">  
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">  
       <li class="active"><a href="#overview" >Overview</a></li>
       <li class=""><a href="#edit" >Edit Company</a></li>  
       <li class=""><a href="#site" >Manage Sites</a></li>  
       <li class=""><a href="#addManagerTag" class="addManager" >Managers</a></li>  
       <li class="" ><a href="#department" >Departments</a></li>  
       <li class=""><a href="#user" >Manage Users</a></li> 
   </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me how to hide the department tab? it should not be present in the tabs

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
$('div.tabbable ul.nav.nav-tabs li:has(a[href="#department"])').hide();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/B3hz7/)

Comment: @Ksc Glad to help..! If you feel anyone of the answers provided here satisfied your need, then try to click on the tick mark available with that answer in order to show your acceptance to the future visitors.. And it is not a compulsion... :)

Comment: Yeah. I know. it says i need to wait 10 more mins :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in html you can use this:

```
 <li class="" style="display:none;" ><a href="#department" >Departments</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'id' to the department element

```
<li id="department" class="" ><a  href="#department" >Departments</a></li>
```

And then add script to hide it:

```
<script>
   $(document)ready(function(){
      $("#department").hide();
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS, to make the element hidden try:

```
h1.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This will hide the element, but the white space will still be there.

Another option is to use:

```
h1.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

This will hide the element and remove the white space where the element previously was located.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<div class="tabbable">  
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">  
       <li class="active"><a href="#overview" >Overview</a></li>
       <li class=""><a href="#edit" >Edit Company</a></li>  
       <li class=""><a href="#site" >Manage Sites</a></li>  
       <li class=""><a href="#addManagerTag" class="addManager" >Managers</a></li>  
       <li class=""><a href="#user" >Manage Users</a></li> 
   </ul>
</div>
```